# How to make code work together ? lua script

Tags: lua, mouse, logitech-gaming-software

How to make the code correctly, so that the recoil is canceled out, and the button is held down together with "q"?

```lua
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("Numlock") then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            if IsKeyLockOn ("capslock") then
                PressAndReleaseKey("Q")
                Sleep(10000)
                PressAndReleaseKey("Q")
            end
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
                Sleep(50)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            repeat
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    if IsKeyLockOn ("capslock") then
                        PressAndReleaseKey("Q")
                        Sleep(10000)
                        PressAndReleaseKey("Q")
                    end
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
                        Sleep(1)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end
    end
end
```

I'm a newbie, I made the code myself. As a result, first the button "Q" works by holding it down for 10 seconds and then releasing it, but I need it all together

```lua
if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
    if IsKeyLockOn ("capslock") then
        PressAndReleaseKey("Q")
        Sleep(10000)
        PressAndReleaseKey("Q")
    end
    repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
        Sleep(50)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end
```

Comment: It's unclear what is needed: should `Q` be pressed while LMB is down or should it be pressed exactly 10 sec from the moment LMB was pressed for the first time?

Comment: When working, this is a code, the button is pressed, which is good. And recoil absorption code doesn't work. we need everything to work together

Comment: Why do you check the state of CapsLock and NumLock?

Comment: @СиестаСоб - How `Q` key should work in the result script?  With 10 sec press time, as previously?  Or its turning off should be triggered somehow else?

Comment: When you press the mouse button, 1 must press the Q button and within 10 seconds must press again. But within 10 seconds the recoil does not work  "repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
        Sleep(50)"